# Angular - declare and initialize array inside an object

Tags: arrays, angular, object

I am trying to declare an array inside an object as follows:

```
data = {
    arr: [],
}
```

However, I want also to declare the type of each element in the array, i.e. something like:

```
data = {
    arr: any = [],
}
```

I have not find the way to do this. Can't I declare the type too?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the type of the object, containing a key `arr` which is an array of type `any` (although it should not be `any`, but you add your typing there )

```js
const data: { arr: any[] } = { arr: [] };
```